# How can I control how close two images in a row are to each other in beamer

Tags: beamer, graphics, subfloats, minipage, columns

I'm trying to add images to a slide for a presentation that I'm preparing but the images are not working with me. I've been able to get the layout I've wanted for the slide using a number of different methods, but each of these ways doesn't give me control over the distance between the images(maybe they do, I just don't know). I've used the `columns` package, the `subfig` package and `\minipage` to move the images around the slide. 
However, in all of these methods, the images appearing in the same row are spread out and it doesn't look good. How can I get the images closer together and more centered on the slide. I've included my best attempt at this. The reason the columns are split .6/.4 is because the images on the left are wider than they are long so I wanted to give those images more room. The images on the left are square images. Thanks!

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test Slide}

\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}

\begin{columns}

\begin{column}{.6\textwidth}
\raggedright
\includegraphics[width=.95\textwidth, height=.3\textwidth]{image1}\\
\includegraphics[width=.95\textwidth, height=.3\textwidth]{image3}
\end{column}

\begin{column}{.4\textwidth}
\raggedleft
\includegraphics[width=.98\textwidth, height=.49\textwidth]{image2}\\
\includegraphics[width=.98\textwidth, height=.49\textwidth]{image4}
\end{column}

\end{columns}

\end{minipage}

\vfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{\textwidth} 

Statement that leads into a list

\begin{itemize}

\item{...}
\item{...}

\end{itemize}

\end{minipage}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `columns`, you could use a tabbed stack, where the inter-row and inter-column gap sizes (currently 0pt and 1em, respectively, in the top set and 6pt and 0em in the bottom set) may be specified.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx,tabstackengine}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test Slide}
\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
\setstackgap{S}{0pt}% <--- GAP BETWEEN ROWS
\setstacktabbedgap{1em}% <--- GAP BETWEEN COLUMNS
\centering\tabbedShortstack{
\includegraphics[width=.6\textwidth, height=.1\textwidth]{example-image-A}&
\includegraphics[width=.35\textwidth, height=.1\textwidth]{example-image-B}\\
\includegraphics[width=.6\textwidth, height=.1\textwidth]{example-image-C}&
\includegraphics[width=.35\textwidth, height=.1\textwidth]{example-image}
}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
\setstackgap{S}{6pt}% <--- GAP BETWEEN ROWS
\setstacktabbedgap{0em}% <--- GAP BETWEEN COLUMNS
\centering\tabbedShortstack{
\includegraphics[width=.1\textwidth, height=.1\textwidth]{example-image-A}&
\includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth, height=.1\textwidth]{example-image-B}\\
\includegraphics[width=.1\textwidth, height=.1\textwidth]{example-image-C}&
\includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth, height=.1\textwidth]{example-image}
}
\end{minipage}

\vfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{\textwidth} 

Statement that leads into a list

\begin{itemize}

\item{...}
\item{...}

\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

How about a simple tabular?
You can adjust the horizontal space between the pictures with the argument of the `@` in the column specification of the tabular. For example you can replace the `\qquad` with `\hspace{...}` and specify an arbitrary distance.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Test Slide}
    \newcommand {\picpath}{pic}
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{c @{\qquad} c}
        \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth, height=.3\textheight, keepaspectratio=true]{\picpath/pic0}
        & \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth, height=.3\textheight, keepaspectratio=true]{\picpath/pic1}
        \\ \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth, height=.3\textheight, keepaspectratio=true]{\picpath/pic2}
        & \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth, height=.3\textheight, keepaspectratio=true]{\picpath/pic3}
    \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
    \vfill

    Statement that leads into a list
    \begin{itemize}
        \item item~0
        \item item~1
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

You can use `\uncover<+->` if you want to let the images appear at different times (see [beamer documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf) page 81).